# Endroid\QR Code

Tags: php, qr-code

How do I save a QR Code in a specific folder after generation?

Below is my example code to generate the qrcode using the library found here: [Endroid](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode)

```
<?php 

    require_once('src/QrCode.php');

    use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

    $qr = new QrCode();

    $qr ->setText('Hello Kent')
        ->setSize(140)
        ->setPadding(10)
        ->setErrorCorrection('high')
        ->setForegroundColor(array('r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0))
        ->setBackgroundColor(array('r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0))
        ->setLabel('My label')
        ->setLabelFontSize(16)
        ->setImageType(IMAGE_TYPE_PNG);
        ->setImagePath('../QRcode')
        ->render('Hello','png');
        ->save();

?>
```

Comment: What do you think `setImagePath()` might do?

Comment: Im just trying that method sir, but it does'nt work.. and id tried also the  setPath() and i got same result. do you have any idea sir how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but try this:

```
//...
$qr ->setText('Hello Kent')
        ->setSize(140)
        ->setPadding(10)
        ->setErrorCorrection('high')
        ->setForegroundColor(array('r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0))
        ->setBackgroundColor(array('r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0))
        ->setLabel('My label')
        ->setLabelFontSize(16)
        ->setImageType(IMAGE_TYPE_PNG);

$file_name = '/path/to/myfile.png';
$qr->writeFile($file_name);
```